# 2D array to calculate squares

Tags: java, arrays, math

I'm making a 2D array that will take the numbers from 1-15 and output the number, the square, and then the cube. I tried to put this into a for loop format to calculate the values instead of having them put in manually. I'm new to 2D arrays so I'm not completely sure what's wrong as I am getting an error message on the system.outprint line

```
int[][] squareCubeArray= new int [3][15];
    for(int i=0;i<=15;i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<=2;j++)
    {
        square = i*i;
        cube = i*i*i;
        
        System.out.println(squareCubeArray[i][i*i][i*i*i]);
    }
```

The output I would like the achieve is something like:

```
Number     Square    Cube
 1          1         1
 2          4         8
 3          9         27
```

... etc up to 15

EDIT: is there a way to do this with a nested for loop? I've started something but it doesn't seem to be working:

```java
int[][] squareCubeArray= new int [15][3];
for(int j=0;j<=14;j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i<=2;i++) {
        squareCubeArray[j][i] = (i+1);
            
        System.out.println(squareCubeArray[j][i] + "\t\t" + squareCubeArray[j][i]*squareCubeArray[j][i] + "\t\t" + squareCubeArray[j][i]*squareCubeArray[j][i]*squareCubeArray[j][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `squareCubeArray[0][i] = i`, `squareCubeArray[1][i] = i * i`, `squareCubeArray[2][i] = i * i * i`. Or more generally: `squareCubeArray[j][i] = (int)Math.pow(i, j + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. With `arr[i][j][k]`, you actually attempt to *fetch* the element from the 3 dimensional array, **not** to store anything in that array;
2. As your array is 2 dimensional, even unreasonable access, like `squareCubeArray[i][i*i][i*i*i]` would end up in a compile time error, as it tries to access 3<sup>rd</sup> dimension of your 2 dimensional array;
3. You probably want to have `[15][3]`, to have 15 arrays of length 3 each, that is 15 rows and 3 columns, and not vice versa;
4. If you insist, that you want to use 2-level (nested) loop, you can do this:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] squareCubeArray = new int[15][3];
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", "Number", "Squared", "Cube");
        for (int i = 0; i < squareCubeArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < squareCubeArray[i].length; j++) {
                squareCubeArray[i][j] = (int) Math.pow(i + 1, j + 1);
            }
        }
        Arrays.stream(squareCubeArray)
                .forEach(arr -> System.out.printf("%-10d%-10d%-10d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]));
    }
}
```

5. However, it is also possible to achieve that with one loop, like:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] squareCubeArray = new int[15][3];
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", "Number", "Squared", "Cube");
        for (int i = 1; i < squareCubeArray.length; i++) {
            int number = i, squared = i * i, cubed = i * i * i;

            //in case you also want to add the calculated elements in your array.
            squareCubeArray[i][0] = number;
            squareCubeArray[i][1] = squared;
            squareCubeArray[i][2] = cubed;

            System.out.printf("%-10d%-10d%-10d\n", number, squared, cubed);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can adjust the `printf` formatting to your wish.

Answer (score 1):

While your logic is correct, there are quite a few errors in your array indexing.

---

First of all, you want to create an array of 15 rows and 3 columns, not the other way around. So something like this:

```
new int[15][3];
```

---

Second, note that there's a difference between an array *index* and the *value* that you want to store or retrieve at that index.

```
squareCubeArray[i][i*i][i*i*i];
```

In the above example, you're not *assigning a value*, but rather *retrieving a value at an index*. What is more, that's a syntax error since `squareCubeArray` is 2-dimensional.

---

Finally, array indices start with 0, whereas you begin with 1.

---

Something like this should work:

```
int[][] squareCubeArray= new int [15][3];
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    int square = i * i;
    int cube = i * i * i;

    squareCubeArray[i-1][0] = i;
    squareCubeArray[i-1][1] = square;
    squareCubeArray[i-1][2] = cube;

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(squareCubeArray[i-1]));
}
```

**EDIT** You can of course also solve this with a nested loop:

```
int[][] squareCubeArray= new int [15][3];
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    int next = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        squareCubeArray[i-1][j] = next;
        next *= i;
    }
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(squareCubeArray[i-1]));
}
```